# Polynomial proof in Real numbers

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, real-numbers

how to prove that there exists a 2 variable polynomial which is bounded below and the range of values is strict subset from the $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Wouldn't any constant work?

Comment: What do you mean "a subset for the $\mathbb R$"?  The header mentions rationals, which are also tagged, but there is no mention of the rationals in the question.

Comment: @Henrik Do you mean for example 0x + 0y  = 0?

Comment: @Lulu the polynomial's range of values must be from any open subset of rational numbers

Comment: That would be an example of what I'm thinking of, yes.

Comment: Please edit your post to state the problem clearly.  $\mathbb R$ refers to the reals, not to the rationals.  The range of a non-constant polynomial can't be a subset of the rationals by the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: @Henrik Would also |x|+|y| work?

Comment: But $|x|+|y|$ is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest thing here is to consider the function $P(x,y)=x^2+y^2$.  This is clearly a polynomial in two variables, it is clearly bounded below by $0$, hence its range is clearly a strict subset of the reals.

To understand more fully what qualifies as a proof here, you need to understand that a polynomial in two variables is *any* function of the form

$$P(x,y)=a_{00}+a_{10}x+a_{01}y+a_{20}x^2+a_{11}xy+a_{02}y^2+a_{30}x^3+\cdots$$

with only a *finite* number of nonzero coefficients $a_{mn}$.  Consequently, here are two other polynomials in two variables that are bounded below (and hence whose range is a strict subset of $\mathbb{R}$):

$$P(x,y)=x^2$$
and
$$P(x,y)=0$$

These make not *look* like proper examples -- $x^2$ looks like a polynomial in only one variable, while $P(x,y)=0$ looks like an equation to be solved -- but they both are.

The take-home message here is that a proof doesn't need to be complicated in order to be correct.  In particular, when you're asked to prove the existence of something with certain specified properties, sometimes a very simple example suffices.